# WooCommerce related products - Load more (ajax)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store where we need to have a lot of related products. We wish to only show 4 to begin with and then a "Show more" function. I would prefer not just to hide the products and then show with jQuery, but have them loaded dynamically with ajax.

I have searched for similar solution, but can't find anything. So I am hoping there are some out there that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

And for the index.php file:

```
<?php
       include 'dbh.php';
     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="products">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 2";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<p>";
            echo $row['product'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['product_name'];
            echo "</p>";
          }
        } else {
          echo "There are no more products.";
        }
         ?>
      </div>
      <button id="btn">Show more products</button>
    </body>
    </html>



<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var productCount = 2;
        $("btn").click(function() {
            productCount += 2;
          $("#data-placeholder").load("loaded_data.php", {
            productNewCount: productCount
          });
        });
    });

<!-- end snippet -->

enter code hereYou need to to use multiple files in Ajax, one where the data loads that you can call loaded_data.php that is going to to get added to the main php file (example: index.php),

    <?php
    include 'dbh.php';//dbh.php is the file that hold the database connection.

    $productNewCount = $POST['productNewCount'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $productNewCount";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $row['product_name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['product'];
        echo "</p>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "There are no more products!";
    }
     ?>
```